# libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Google Colab project

Tags: c++, google-colaboratory, gsl

I'm using Google Colab to compile and run some code in CUDA and C++ (mostly because I dont have a CUDA capable GPU). For reference, the project Im trying to replicate is here:

https://github.com/franrruiz/shopper-src

For the project I need to install and configure the GSL Library, which I have done by following these steps:

1. Download GSL library from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/
2. Upload zipped file into Colab
3. Run the following code in Colab

```
# Unzip and change directory
!unzip "gsl-2.6.zip"
%cd "/content/gsl-2.6"

# Gives permissions
!chmod 755 "/content/gsl-2.6/configure"

# Configure
!./configure
!make
!make check
!make install
```

Compiling the code works perfectly fine, but when I attempt to run the code on a workable dataset I get the following error:

```
/content/shopper: error while loading shared libraries: 
libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**What I've already Tried**

```
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/contents/gsl-2.6/.libs"
```

and

```
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
```

However, neither of them fixed the issue. If it's helpful,

```
!sudo find / -name "libgsl.so.25"
```

returns

```
/usr/local/lib/libgsl.so.25
/content/gsl-2.6/.libs/libgsl.so.25
```

So we know the files exist. I just cant seem to point my code to it correctly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with a different library. I also tried the `export`, which does not work, seems like the python in colab does not read environmental variables.

My solution is the following

```
!ln -s /usr/local/lib/<your_shared_library> /usr/lib/<your_shared_library>
```